# finding (n*logn) minimal elements from sum of two arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have some problem in my homework, I'm given two arrays A,B (they are sorted) with n elements each one, I need to find (n*logn) minimal elements (or n if it is possible) from the array which cosists of elements which is sum of one element from array A and one element from array B, `total number of elemnts in C will be n^2`, - `C = {a+b | a belongs to A, b belongs to B}`, I need to make it with complexity O(n*logn).
Thanks in advance for any help!

P.S. I tried to solve it but I have some problems. I know that the first element will be `a1 + b1`, a1 first element from A, b1 first element from B.

#### edited

Also all elements in C are different.

Comment: The question is not very clear. You want to create n^2 elements in nlogn time? Wouldn't that reverse the ageing process and sell for millions?

Comment: @davin: I need to find minimal (n*logn) elements (it may be without ordering), I need to create new array only for n*logn elements not n^2, for example I know that a1+b1 will be the minimum in the new array C so it will be included to n*logn minimal elements of sum as I defined

Comment: You have C defined as a set. Does this mean that it cannot contain duplicates? Can A and B contain duplicates?

Comment: @Thom Smith: Yes A, and B can contain duplicates, but to make it easier I can assume that there is no duplication in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not giving you the answer, but here are a few hints to get you thinking in the right direction.

So let's say you have. Keep in mind that these lists are already sorted, this is very important.
{a1,a2,a3}
{b1,b2,b3}

As you correctly said, the first element is a1+b1. Why? Because those are the smallest numbers in both arrays, so their sum will be the smallest.

Now what options do you have for the second element? Remember that the list is sorted!
Could it be a1+b2? 
Could it be a1+b3? 
And then for the opposite, 
Could it be b1+a2? 
Could it be b1+a3?

Could it be b2+a2?
(two yes answers and three no answers above)

Using this you should be able to figure out how you find the second smallest element and from here it should be easy to find how to do that for all elements.

If you are still confused, ask questions in the comments.

GL!

Comment: I thought exactly as You are describing but every time I need to make more and more decisions, I can't do it with O(n*logn) such way, am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe you are, maybe I am :) Let's figure it out. Why do you think that you need to run through more and more decisions?

Comment: if every array consists of 1000 elments and I'm only on 100, I need to make dicisions from every 99 which were before, a lot of pain

Comment: Again, I could be wrong, but it seems to me that you only have to do 3 checks at any time. Let's express the numbers this way: {x x+a0 x+a0+a1} and {y y+b0 y+b0+b1}. Then let's say the first sum pair is x+y and the second is going to be x+y+b0 (0 and 1 respectively). Now for the next one you should compare the following: y+ (x+a0) vs (x+a0)+ (y+b0) vs x+ (y+b0+b1). There's no point looking more to the right, since all will be bigger and there's no point going more to the left since all the prev should've been explored before. What do you think?

Comment: There might be a bit more going on (in the prev example if you advance to x+a0 and y+b0 I *THINK* that will change the way you check numbers at the next step a bit), but anyway, that's the general idea, you can figure out the specifics of it. You will always only be looking at a constant number of pairs at every step so the time-complexity is equal to the size of your solution.

Answer (score 3):

this code below will do the trick it uses the hint you gave 2 elements are sorted and it's order is number of elements needed to find:

```
int m = n *lon(n);
a[n] = max_int;
b[n] = max_int;

for(int i=0,j=0;i+j<m;)
{
    if(a[i+1]+b[j] < a[i]+b[j+1])
    {
        c[i+j] = a[i+1]+b[j];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        c[i+j] = a[i]+b[j+1];
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gajet you beat me to it, and also added the code. :-)  I was trying to avoid code since this is HW.  But +1 anyway! :-)

Comment: you are right guess it was better i didn't insert the code! but just after i submited my answer i saw the first answer was accepted already!

Answer (score 0):

Find the smallest element in A (lets call it a) and the smallest element in B (b). The smallest element in C is a + b.

If you need the position of that element in C and if first element is a1 + b1, second a1 + b2 etc. the position of wanted element will be `pos(a) * size(B) + pos(b)`.

Comment: can You give me please example, I'm not sure that I understood it

Answer (score 0):

This is a common homework problem.  Since the A and B arrays are sorted, you can do a pairwise merge, almost like merge sort, the only difference being that you are trying to compare the sums, not the numbers themselves.  In other words, say your pointers are currently at A_i and B_j, and you just added A_i + B_j to the list C.  Next element might be A_i + B_{j+1} or it might be A_{i+1} + B_j.  Simply see which is smaller, and then move that pointer forward.

It seems you are already on it, and anothem's answer (or rather the questions!) must have already guided you in the right direction, but if you have more questions, feel free to ask.

[PS: No reason to fear duplicates in arrays A, B or C.  **Duplicates don't change anything for this question.**  Consider the data structure to be list, instead of set.]